# Difference between Actorref.tell and inbox.send in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

So i have started learning Akka and trying out the examples in typesafe.
So the Hello Akka app has the following code :

```
    import akka.actor.{ ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props, Actor, Inbox }
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case object Greet
case class WhoToGreet(who: String)
case class Greeting(message: String)

class Greeter extends Actor {
  var greeting = ""

  def receive = {
    case WhoToGreet(who) => greeting = s"hello, $who"
    case Greet           => sender ! Greeting(greeting) // Send the current greeting back to the sender
  }
}

object HelloAkkaScala extends App {

  // Create the 'helloakka' actor system
  val system = ActorSystem("helloakka")

  // Create the 'greeter' actor
  val greeter = system.actorOf(Props[Greeter], "greeter")

  // Create an "actor-in-a-box"
  val inbox = Inbox.create(system)

  // Tell the 'greeter' to change its 'greeting' message
  greeter.tell(WhoToGreet("akka"), ActorRef.noSender)

  // Ask the 'greeter for the latest 'greeting'
  // Reply should go to the "actor-in-a-box"
  inbox.send(greeter, Greet)

  // Wait 5 seconds for the reply with the 'greeting' message
  val Greeting(message1) = inbox.receive(5.seconds)
  println(s"Greeting: $message1")

  // Change the greeting and ask for it again
  greeter.tell(WhoToGreet("typesafe"), ActorRef.noSender)
  inbox.send(greeter, Greet)
  val Greeting(message2) = inbox.receive(5.seconds)
  println(s"Greeting: $message2")

  val greetPrinter = system.actorOf(Props[GreetPrinter])
  // after zero seconds, send a Greet message every second to the greeter with a sender of the greetPrinter
  system.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 1.second, greeter, Greet)(system.dispatcher, greetPrinter)

}

// prints a greeting
class GreetPrinter extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Greeting(message) => println(message)
  }
}
```

Now i am stuck in understanding what is the difference between ,

```
greeter.tell(WhoToGreet("akka"), ActorRef.noSender)
```

and

```
inbox.send(greeter, Greet)
```

From my understanding the actor starts its own thread at the end of the

```
val inbox = Inbox.create(system)
```

Can someone please explain what exactly does the Actorref.tell do and then what is exactly achieved by the Inbox.send line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The purpose of `tell`, also represented as `!` is to send a message to an actor.  As actors communicate via message passing, `tell` is the mechanism used to support that message passing.  It is asynchronous to the caller, so that once the caller calls `tell`, they are decoupled from the receiving and processing of that message by the target actor instance.  In this particular example, the code is using tell to cause the greeter actor to update its internal state.  As this interaction does not result in a response of any kind (the receiving actor is not sending a message back to the sender in response to this request), `tell` alone is sufficient here.

For getting a greeting response from the greeter, the interaction is slightly different.  In this interaction, the sender is expecting a response message.  This type of request/response interaction can be handed via `ask` (i.e. `?`) in which the caller gets a `Future` back that will be completed when the receiver replies but `ask` was not used here.  In this example, the coder got the request/response semantic by using an `Inbox` instead which can behave as an actor and it eliminates the need for futures.  The inbox must look like an `ActorRef` to the receiver allowing it to route a response back to it with the following line:

```
sender ! Greeting(greeting)
```

The `sender()` method returns the `ActorRef` of whoever sent in the message being currently processed.  The `Inbox` must be able to represent itself as an `ActorRef` for this to work.  But as I said earlier, you also could have used `ask` here to get the request/response interaction working.  I think it's just a matter of choice.  The bottom line is that `tell` is used for the fire and forget interaction model and the inbox (or another actor or `ask`) can be used when a request/response semantic is needed.

Comment: So does that mean that if i comment out the "inbox.send(greeter, Greet)" calls i will still see the "receive" method being called in the Greeter actor class ?

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya, in that example, the `receive` partial function will be invoked two times; one from the `tell` of `WhoToGreet` and one from the `inbox.send` of the `Greet` message.  If you comment out the `inbox.send` then `receive` will only be invoked one time for the `WhoToGreet` message.

Answer (score 2):

When you do the following you are dealing directly with an `ActorRef`

```
greeter.tell(WhoToGreet("akka"), ActorRef.noSender)
```

On the other hand, when you use an `Inbox` you are dealing something that is not exactly an actor but *actor-like*. One scenario where this is helpful is when you don't want to create your own actor but still want to interact with other actors asynchronously. Please see [this](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.4/index.html#akka.actor.Inbox)

*An Inbox is an actor-like object which is interrogated from the outside. It contains an actor whose reference can be passed to other actors as usual and it can watch other actors’ lifecycle.*

The actor runs on the a threadpool (configured using a dispatcher). You can decide either by configuration or by putting in your code where which dispatcher that actor use for its execution.