# Akka consolidate concurrent database requests

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I want to be able to make concurrent requests to multiple data repositories and consolidate the results.  I am trying to understand if my approach is at all valid or if there is a better way to approach this problem.  I am definitely new to Akka / Spray / Scala and really want to get a better understanding of how to properly build these components. Any suggestions / Tips would be greatly appreciated.  Trying to wrap my head around the use of actors and futures for this type of implementation.

**Spray Service:**

```
trait DemoService extends HttpService with Actor with ActorLogging {
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds) // needed for `?` below
  val mongoMasterActor = context.actorOf(Props[MongoMasterActor], "redisactor")
  val dbMaster = context.actorOf(Props[DbMasterActor], "dbactor")

  val messageApiRouting =
        path("summary" / Segment / Segment) { (dataset, timeslice) =>
          onComplete(getDbResponses(dbMaster, dataset, timeslice)) {
            case Success(dbMessageResponse) => complete(s"The result was $dbMessageResponse")
            case Failure(ex) => complete(s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}")
          }
        }

  /** Passes the desired actor reference for a specific dataset and timeslice for summary data retrieval
    *
    * @param mongoActor an actor reference to the RedisActor that will handle the appropriate request routing
    * @param dataset The dataset for which the summary has been requested
    * @param timeslice The timeslice (Month, Week, Day, etc.) for which the summary has been requested
    */
  def getSummary(mongoActor: ActorRef, dataset: String, timeslice: String): Future[DbMessageResponse] = {
    log.debug(s"dataset: $dataset  timeslice: $timeslice")
    val dbMessage = DbMessage("summary", dataset + timeslice)
    (mongoActor ? dbMessage).mapTo[DbMessageResponse]
  }

  def getDbResponses(dbActor: ActorRef, dataset: String, timeslice: String): Future[SummaryResponse] = {
    log.debug(s"dataset: $dataset  timeslice: $timeslice")
    val dbMessage = DbMessage("summary", dataset + timeslice)
    (dbActor ? dbMessage).mapTo[SummaryResponse]
  }

  def getSummaryPayload(mongoSummary: DbMessageResponse, redisSummary: DbMessageResponse): String = {
    mongoSummary.response + redisSummary.response
  }

}
```

**Akka Actor / Future mock db requests:**

```
class DbMasterActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {


  private var originalSender: ActorRef = _

  //TODO: Need to add routing to the config to limit instances
  val summaryActor = context.actorOf(Props(new SummaryActor), "summaryactor")

  def receive = {

    case msg: DbMessage => {
      this.originalSender = sender
      msg.query match {
        case "summary" => {

          getDbResults().onComplete{
            case Success(result) => originalSender ! result
            case Failure(ex) => log.error(ex.getMessage)

          }
        }
      }
    }

    //If not match log an error
    case _ => log.error("Received unknown message: {} ")

  }


  def getDbResults(): Future[SummaryResponse] = {
    log.debug("hitting db results")
    val mongoResult = Future{ Thread.sleep(500); "Mongo"}
    val redisResult = Future{ Thread.sleep(800); "redis"}

    for{
      mResult <- mongoResult
      rResult <- redisResult

    } yield SummaryResponse(mResult, rResult)

  }
}
```

Comment: For-comprehension over the futures looks fine to me, if that's the question.

Comment: Looks good to me also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the reading of Effective Akka by Jamie Allen, I am going to attempt to apply his "Cameo" pattern suggestion.

Slideshare:
http://www.slideshare.net/shinolajla/effective-akka-scalaio

Github:
https://github.com/jamie-allen/effective_akka

I think what I created will work, but doesn't sound like the best approach based on Jamie's comments in his talks.  I will update / edit back to this post what I have implemented (or try to).

**Summary Actor (Cameo Actor):**

```
object SummaryResponseHandler {
  case object DbRetrievalTimeout

  def props(mongoDb: ActorRef, redisDb: ActorRef, originalSender: ActorRef): Props = {
    Props(new SummaryResponseHandler(mongoDb, redisDb, originalSender))
  }
}

class SummaryResponseHandler(mongoDb: ActorRef, redisDb: ActorRef,
                             originalSender: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import SummaryResponseHandler._
  var mongoSummary, redisSummary: Option[String] = None
  def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case MongoSummary(summary) =>
      log.debug(s"Received mongo summary: $summary")
      mongoSummary = summary
      collectSummaries
    case RedisSummary(summary) =>
      log.debug(s"Received redis summary: $summary")
      redisSummary = summary
      collectSummaries
    case DbRetrievalTimeout =>
      log.debug("Timeout occurred")
      sendResponseAndShutdown(DbRetrievalTimeout)
  }

  def collectSummaries = (mongoSummary, redisSummary) match {
    case (Some(m), Some(r)) =>
      log.debug(s"Values received for both databases")
      timeoutMessager.cancel
      sendResponseAndShutdown(DataSetSummary(mongoSummary, redisSummary))
    case _ =>
  }

  def sendResponseAndShutdown(response: Any) = {
    originalSender ! response
    log.debug("Stopping context capturing actor")
    context.stop(self)
  }

  import context.dispatcher
  val timeoutMessager = context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(
    250 milliseconds, self, DbRetrievalTimeout)
}

class SummaryRetriever(mongoDb: ActorRef, redisDb: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = {
    case GetSummary(dataSet) =>
      log.debug("received dataSet")
      val originalSender = sender
      val handler = context.actorOf(SummaryResponseHandler.props(mongoDb,redisDb, originalSender), "cameo-message-handler")
      mongoDb.tell(GetSummary(dataSet), handler)
      redisDb.tell(GetSummary(dataSet), handler)
    case _ => log.debug(s"Unknown result $GetSummary(datset)")
  }

}
```

**Common:**

```
case class GetSummary(dataSet: String)
case class DataSetSummary(
   mongo: Option[String],
   redis: Option[String]
)

case class MongoSummary(
    summary: Option[String]
                         )

case class RedisSummary(
   summary: Option[String]
                         )

trait MongoProxy extends Actor with ActorLogging
trait RedisProxy extends Actor with ActorLogging
```

**Mock Stubs:**

```
class MongoProxyStub extends RedisProxy {
  val summaryData = Map[String, String](
    "dataset1" -> "MongoData1",
    "dataset2" -> "MongoData2")

  def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case GetSummary(dataSet: String) =>
      log.debug(s"Received GetSummary for ID: $dataSet")
      summaryData.get(dataSet) match {
        case Some(data) => sender ! MongoSummary(Some(data))
        case None => sender ! MongoSummary(Some(""))
      }
  }
}

class RedisProxyStub extends MongoProxy{
  val summaryData = Map[String, String](
    "dataset1" -> "RedisData1",
    "dataset2" -> "RedisData2")

  def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case GetSummary(dataSet: String) =>
      log.debug(s"Received GetSummary for ID: $dataSet")
      summaryData.get(dataSet) match {
        case Some(data) => sender ! RedisSummary(Some(data))
        case None => sender ! RedisSummary(Some(""))
      }
  }
}
```

**Boot (You should use test, but was just wanting to run from boot):**

```
object Boot extends App{

  val system = ActorSystem("DbSystem")

  val redisProxy = system.actorOf(Props[RedisProxyStub], "cameo-success-mongo")
  val mongoProxy = system.actorOf(Props[MongoProxyStub], "cameo-success-redis")
  val summaryRetrieverActor = system.actorOf(Props(new SummaryRetriever(redisProxy, mongoProxy)), "cameo-retriever1")

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  val future = summaryRetrieverActor ? GetSummary("dataset1")
  val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[DataSetSummary]
  println(Some(result.mongo).x)
  println(result.redis)

  system.shutdown()

}
```

**Application Config:**

```
akka.loglevel = "DEBUG"
akka.event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
akka.actor.debug.autoreceive = on
akka.actor.debug.lifecycle = on
akka.actor.debug.receive = on
akka.actor.debug.event-stream = on
```