# Java-Akka: Assemble message from multiple actors

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I am new to Akka. I have 4 actors.

Actor1 sends Message1 to Actor4. 
Actor2 sends Message2 to Actor4. 
Actor3 sends Message3 to Actor4.

Actor4 should create Message4 when it receives 1 message of type Message1, 1 Message of type Message2 and 2 messages of type Message3.

Message4 = (Message1, Message2, Message3a, Message3b, Message3c)

What would be the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a task which depends on other tasks being completed whilst others can be done in parallel, you want to use futures, I have answered a question like this already, this is probably a duplicate question, and just a variation of the more general problem of performing tasks in parallel and distrubuting them across resources as best as possible, but anyway futures give a more clean solution to this problem in my opinion, check out my answer here
[Executing Dependent tasks in parallel in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855045/executing-dependent-tasks-in-parallel-in-java/25800299#25800299).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Snickers3192, that you can use futures.  You could also look into something like the Cameo Pattern from Jamie Allen.  I have created some crude examples in another stackoverflow thread.  These are all Scala and not Java.

[Futures and Cameo Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895241/akka-consolidate-concurrent-database-requests)